# Setting value of a JScrollPane

Tags: jscrollpane

INTRODUCTION

1. I am trying to set the vertical scroll position of a JScrollPane
2. The scrollpane doesn't have a vertical scrollbar but I want to scroll the view.
3. I am able to successfully do this within an AdjustmentListener, using getVerticalScrollBar.setValue(x).
4. However, I want to do this from a regular method, not an event listener.
5. When I write this code in a separate method, it just doesn't scroll it.

TRIED ONE ALTERNATIVE

1. I tried using the invokeLater() option (placing setValue(x) method inside an invokeLater()), and it is not working for me.
2. I don't know why it doesn't work, which is why I didn't bother posting the code (too long).

TRIED ANOTHER ALTERNATIVE

1. I created a custom AdjustmentEvent and tried to fire it programmatically.
2. I used the method scrollbar.processEvent(e).
3. However, I get an error saying something along the lines "The method processEvent(AWTEvent) from type Container is not visible".

MY TWO QUESTIONS

1. What can I do to achieve my objective of moving the scrollbar programmatically and NOT within an event listener.
2. My second question is, WHY DOES THE setValue() METHOD NOT DO WHAT IT IS SUPPOSED TO DO. I mean, I don't know what version of Java we are at, but isn't it kind of ridiculous that this hasn't been fixed? The setValue() method seems absolutely pointless outside an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the `ViewPort` and then moving the `viewPosition`

Comment: Maybe my code is wrong but I am moving the position to new Point(0, 35) and nothing occurs. Maybe my code is wrong? I have a JTree inside my JScrollPane.

Comment: It won't move beyond its bounds.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588100/jtextarea-in-jscrollpane-view-coordinate-translation and here http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/swing/JViewport/setViewPosition(Point%20p).html but I have no idea how good the info in the second is or how old.

Comment: Okay... here is my full question with an SSCCE illustrating different examples. I could have probably edited this post with the SSCCE but anyway... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070167/jscrollpane-setvalue-failing-bigtime-with-sscce